# Can I write custom field data which will echo in custom function in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my Flexile Content layout with  custom fields:

```
<h2 class="mb-half"><?php the_sub_field('form_two_title')?></h2>
<p class="mb-3 lead"><?php the_sub_field('form_two_text')?></p>
```

and I need to write them in my custom function of functions.php witch echo.

First of all, I need to find a way to call that layout, but is it possible to write custom fields in echo section?

I have something in that way:

```
echo '<h2 class="mb-half">.the_sub_field('form_two_title').</h2>';
```

but compiler do not recognize "form_two_title" constant.

Do I need to call `get_row_layout()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are calling is not a valid PHP:

```
echo '<h2 class="mb-half">.the_sub_field('form_two_title').</h2>';
```

Try fixing it like this:

```
echo '<h2 class="mb-half">'.get_sub_field('form_two_title').'</h2>';
```

Comment: good advice, it is working, but form_two_title is empty, do I need to call get_row_layout() ? cause that content field is on my page template. but here his values are not recognized

Comment: The correct syntax for your function should be described here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_sub_field/

Comment: When you are using `echo` you should go for `get_sub_field`, without `echo` it is `the_sub_field`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Already tried that, all get_row_layouts are in switch on my Template page, but in fucntions.php  I can not write data, cause In some reason they do not exist

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "cannot write data"? Can you update your question with the code you have in your `functions.php` ?

Comment: already solve that, but can you help me? I found problem to transform <img class="img" src="<?php echo $thumb_img[0]; ?>"> to php code in my custom class

Comment: please accept the answer and ask a separate question if you are having different issues.